# How to get json object property without using OPENJSON

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, open-json

Following is my script to get specific value(OldPTValue, NewPTValue) from
table `HistoryTracking`.
I'm using `OPENJSON` but getting compatibility issue.
Is there any way to get data without using `OPENJSON` in sql server 2016?

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT [Number] 
        FROM OPENJSON( CHT.OldValues, '$.Employee' ) 
        WITH ([Number] NVARCHAR(25) '$.PaymentTerms')) AS OldPTValue, 
    (
        SELECT [Number] 
        FROM OPENJSON( CHT.NewValues, '$.Employee' ) 
        WITH ([Number] NVARCHAR(25) '$.PaymentTerms')
    ) AS NewPTValue,
    CHT.InsertedBy,
    CHT.InsertedDate 
FROM HistoryTracking CHT 
ORDER BY CHT.Employee, CHT.InsertedDate desc
```

Comment: If you're experiencing compatibility problems your database's compatibility level. 2016 supports openjson but it requires compatibility level 130 or higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it seems like that's what you may need there.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks @Jaro Kolton your suggestion help me to complete my query.